# Yaml Pipeline is in queue and not running

Tags: yaml, queue

resources:
repositories:

- repository: DevOps
  type: git
  name: DevOps
  trigger:
  branches:
  include:
  - master

trigger: none

pool:
name: DevOps-VMSS

parameters:

- name: Environment
  values:

  - 'Runbooks'
- name: AzureStorageAccountName
  values:

  - 'AzureStorage.AccountName-UAT'
  - 'AzureStorage.AccountName-PreProd'
- name: AzureStorageAccountKey
  values:

  - 'AzureStorage.AccountKey-UAT'
  - 'AzureStorage.AccountKey-PreProd'
- name: RunbookCopyLiveFilesContainers
  values:

  - 'Runbook.CopyLiveFiles.Containers-UAT'
  - 'Runbook.CopyLiveFiles.Containers-PreProd'

variables:

- group: 'Runbooks'
- name: AzureStorage.AccountName
  value: ${{parameters.AzureStorageAccountName}}
- name: AzureStorage.AccountKey
  value: ${{parameters.AzureStorageAccountKey}}
- name: Runbook.CopyLiveFiles.Containers
  value: ${{parameters.RunbookCopyLiveFilesContainers}}

jobs:

- deployment: Deploy
  displayName: Copy files from Live
  environment:
  name: Runbooks
  resourceType: virtualMachine
  tags: 'Prod-Logstash'
  strategy:
  runOnce:
  deploy:
  steps:
  - checkout: DevOps
  - task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
  filePath: 'Runbooks/CopyStorageAccountContainers.ps1'
  arguments: '-SourceStorageAccountName ''$(Runbook.CopyLiveFiles.SourceAccountName)'' -SourceStorageAccountKey ''$(Runbook.CopyLiveFiles.SourceAccountKey)'' -DestinationStorageAccountName ''$(AzureStorage.AccountName)'' -DestinationStorageAccountKey ''$(AzureStorage.AccountKey)'' -ContainersIncluded ''$(Runbook.CopyLiveFiles.Containers)'''

I tried running, but it is still in queue